# Using set of function c++

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I am trying to create a set of function pointers in c++ but getting error while inserting / deleting elements from it.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void func(int x) {
  cout<<x;
}

int main() {
  set <function<void (int)>> mine;
  mine.insert(func);
  return 0;
}
```

i am getting error 
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_function.h:386:20: error: no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘const std::function’ and ‘const std::function’). 
I think that this problem is because of operator that will be used to compare set values , can someone suggest how to make this work ? 
How can i write a comparator for function pointers in this case ?

Comment: A function pointer != `std::function`. A set of function pointers would look like `std::set<void(*)(int)>`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat can you suggest a way by which i can use set of functions then

Comment: do you need to compare functions? do you need them to be sorted? what does it mean for one function to be smaller then another? Maybe you want an unordered container instead?

Comment: I'd suggest a `std::vector<std::function>` over a `std::set<std::function>`

Comment: @user463035818 I don't think `std::function` can be hashed either...

Comment: @MaxLanghof they could be wrapped, though I was trying to find out if OP really needs an `operator<` and hence choose a `set` or if it is the other way around (chose `set` and now tries to get a `<`). I mean there are cases where it can be meaningful to have an ordering on functions, but its not clear whether that is the [X or the Y](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here ;)

Comment: If you are trying to protect against double insertion into the function sequence you execute... don't. It's an exercise in futility, and is also likely why the standard library doesn't bother giving you the illusion it's working.

Comment: @Uddhav So what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @freakish i am trying to check whether the same entry is not pushed to the set more than once.

Comment: Since you don't seem to be inserting functors/lambdas into the set, what's wrong with `std::set<void(*)(int)>`?

Comment: @Uddhav So you want to avoid duplicates. Now the next question is: how do you define a duplicate of `std::function`? This is far from trivial because in simple case of function pointers you can simply compare their addresses. But in case of `std::function` they may hold the same function pointer inside but still be different `std::function` objects. Because that's just a thin wrapper in case of function pointer. And in general case its even more complicated.

Comment: @freakish If we make a custom `std::function`-like class, it should be possible to implement `<` with some type erasure tricks.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat With a custom class `MyFunc`, with possibly a static "id" it is trivial to simply implement `std::hash<MyFunc>` and use `std::unordered_set`. And I would suggest doing that.

Comment: @freakish If I understand your suggestion correctly (setting id for each instance to a static 'instance count' incremented in costructor), that would make two `MyFunc` constructed from identical function pointers not equal. I think a more robust solution would be to store `std::type_index` in `MyFunc`, in addition to a `bool (*less)(const void *, const void *)` (which would be set to a proper comparator in the templated constructor). So `<` would first compare type indices, and if they're equal it would resort to using the comparator via the function pointer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to store just function pointers, you don't need `std::function`:

```
using MyFunctionPointer = void(*)(int);

void func(int x);

std::set<MyFunctionPointer> orderedSet;

int main()
{
    orderedSet.emplace(func);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TMxQDJ)

This works because you can compare (for `std::set`) or hash (for `std::unordered set`) function pointer values. But comparing or hashing `std::function` instances is not implemented in the standard library, and there is no portable way to add that after the fact.

Edit: As pointed out by **@HolyBlackCat**, while the builtin `operator<` is not required to induce the required total order on function pointers, `std::less` (as used by `std::set`) is [required to do so](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) for any pointer.

Comment: Isn't relational comparison of pointers defined only for array pointer (with one-past-the-end pointer) or pointers to members?

Comment: @DanielLangr Dang, you're right. I only looked at equality comparison.

Comment: My bad, it will actually work, since `std::less` is defined for pointers of any type. Didn't know that.